# Error Al mostrar Un dato

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas quisiera saber como solucionar este error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\Horarios\paginas\actualizarsubjects.php:12 
Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Horarios\paginas\actualizarsubjects.php on line 12
```

y que es simplemente que quiero llevar datos de un formulario a otro en paginas diferentes mi clave principal en la base de datos es `varchar`, a la hora de traerlos si solo escribo números los muestra pero, si escribo letras y números como quiero me sale ese error agradezco su ayuda.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "../php/connect.php";
if(!$_SESSION['verificar']){
//
}
else {
require_once "../php/connect.php";
    $usu =$_GET['codigomateria'];
    $query="SELECT codigomateria,creditos,nombre FROM materias WHERE codigomateria=".$usu;
    $consulta1=$mysqli->query($query);
    while($fila=$consulta1->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
  $codigomateria=$fila['codigomateria'];
  $nombre=$fila['nombre'];
  $creditos=$fila['creditos'];
}
}
echo $_SESSION['user'];
```

?>

Comment: Bienvenido Miguel. Antes de hacer el `fetch` debes verificar que la consulta es válida y que devuelve datos. De todos modos, nada podemos hacer si no muestras cuál es el código problemático [editando la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/124931/edit).

Comment: Por favor [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/124931/edit) poniendo en ella el código, no en un comentario. Gracias.

Comment: Los criterios de tipo cadena, deben estar rodeados por comillas simples, ejemplo: `$query="SELECT codigomateria,creditos,nombre FROM materias WHERE codigomateria='".$usu."'";`. Ahora bien, **esa consulta es totalmente vulnerable a la Inyección SQL**. Prueba si funciona así, entonces te propondré una solución implementando código seguro mediante el uso de consultas preparadas.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias ya funciona corectamente, no sabia que era por error en las comillas muchisimas gracias.